# Mogenerator and Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, core-data, mogenerator

The `Mogenerator` GitHub page suggests that the latest version can generate Swift code. Can anyone tell me what flag I need to pass on the command line to trigger this feature. The *ReadMe* doesn't seem to say, and all of the other relevant documentation I've found on the web pre-dates the release of Swift. Here's the command I'm using at the moment (it produces Objective-C), what do I need to add?

```
mogenerator --v2 --model TagField/TagField.xcdatamodeld -O TagField/Model
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

```
DDGetoptOption optionTable[] = 
{
    // Long                 Short  Argument options
    {@"v2",                 '2',   DDGetoptNoArgument},
    {@"model",              'm',   DDGetoptRequiredArgument},
    ...
    {@"swift",              'S',   DDGetoptNoArgument},
    {nil,                   0,     0},
};
```

in https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/blob/master/mogenerator.m I assume that

```
mogenerator --swift ...
```

should to the trick.

Comment: Or directly from calling `mogenerator --help`: `--swift                   Generate Swift templates instead of Objective-C`

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: Good point :) I hadn't installed or run it at all, only browsed the source code, and somehow missed the help text.